# Regex for string or space ending

Tags: regex, powershell

I am looking for word matches from a lookup, to an excel sheet.

Say, for example, the word I am looking for is stackexchange.

I can have the following:

- stackexchange
- stackexchange is ok
- \stackexchange\
- my_stackexchange-is ok
- my-stackexchange_is ok
- my stackexchange.
- my.stackexchange.is.ok
- .stackexchange.

I cannot have

- mystackexchange is ok my
- stackexchangeis ok
- mystackexchangeisok

I have managed all of them, apart from if the word group starts or ends with stackexchange e.g.

- stackexchange is ok
- my stackexchange

I can handle

- .stackexchange.
- \stackexchange\

Just not

- stackexchange is
- my stackexchange

If that makes sense (sorry if I am labouring a point).

The regex I have  is

```
[-|_| ]?[^a-zA-Z\d]stackexchange[-|_| ]?[^a-zA-Z\d]
```

Any ideas people?

Comment: `(?:^|[-_ ]?[^a-zA-Z\d])stackexchange(?:$|[-_ ]?[^a-zA-Z\d])` or `(?<=^|[-_ ]?[^a-zA-Z\d])stackexchange(?=$|[-_ ]?[^a-zA-Z\d])`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew - Just what I needed, I thought it would be somethign fairly trivial, but not that great at REGEX yet.  Thanks again.

Comment: [Groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) are rather basic notions in regex, I suggest you devote a couple of minutes to read about them to avoid such issues in future.